# How to use pandoc grid table extension

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I want to use grid tables in Markdown doc.

My markdown with grid tables:

```
# Grid tables

## Fist example

+-------------------+-------------------+
| Grid Tables       | Are Beautiful     |
+===================+===================+
|                   | In code and docs  |
| Easy to read      |                   |
|                   |                   |
+-------------------+-------------------+
| Exceptionally flexible and powerful   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

## Second

+---------------------+----------+
| Property            | Earth    |
+=============+=======+==========+
|             | min   | -89.2 °C |
| Temperature +-------+----------+
| 1961-1990   | mean  | 14 °C    |
|             +-------+----------+
|             | min   | 56.7 °C  |
+-------------+-------+----------+

## End

*The end.*
```

Then I using pandoc converting to pdf:

```
pandoc -s -o ./test.pdf --from=markdown+grid_tables ./test.md
```

Resul isn't correct:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your pandoc version is too old; check with `pandoc -v`. Grid table support was added in pandoc 2.19.

Comment: It perfectly works for odt, but not for pdf - it needs some latex conf?

Comment: Are you using the default template or a custom LaTeX template? If the latter then try with the default template. Otherwise this might warrant a new question.

Comment: I didn't specify a template, ie I assume that pandos uses the default template

Comment: That shouldn't happen then. Can you post a separate question with the relevant details?